# How to make a 2D array of coordinates based on a 2D array "map"

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, coordinate-systems

The for loops appear to be reading my list incorrectly. How can I rewrite this to get to the desired output? Any help or corrections is appreciated!

```
    public static String[][] map2 = {{"-","#","#"},
                                     {"#","-","-"},
                                     {"#","D","#"}};

    public static int[][] readMap(String[][] map){
        int[][] wallAt = new int[map.length * map[0].length][2];   
        for(int y = 0; y < map.length ; y++){                   
            for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++){               
                if(map[x][y].equals("#")){                     
                    wallAt[x][0] = x;                          
                    wallAt[x][1] = y;
                }  
                else{              
                    wallAt[x][0] = 999;
                    wallAt[x][1] = 999;
                }
            }
        }
        return wallAt;                                             
    }
```

Using:

```
    public static void test2DArray(int[][] s){   
        for(int[] i : s){                      
            for(int j : i){
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }    
    }
```

To print out `wallAt`,
I would expect:

```
999 999            
0 1  
0 2  
1 0  
999 999  
999 999  
2 0  
999 999  
2 2
```

What I get:

```
0 2  
999 999  
2 2  
0 0  
0 0  
0 0  
0 0  
0 0  
0 0
```

Comment: What's D and what's the purpose of test2array method here? @GabeGalyon

Comment: I suggest learning how to use a debugger in IDEs.

Comment: the non "#"s are relatively unimportant, the "D"s represent doors, that isn't actually implemented yet. @MS90

Comment: the test2DArray was provided in case I made a mistake there and not in readMap. test2Darray is just a method I am using to print wallAt to check its contents.  @MS90

Comment: The mistake is in `readMap` method. To find out what it is, please update your post with what this method is supposed to do. In other words, why do you expect the result to be `999...`?

Comment: Take a look at my answer iand if it suits your needs make it accepted. @GabeGalyon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK except that you didn't go pass array[2][1] at all with your code. What you need is to implement a counter, because you had made 2d array out of multidimensional-array, and 2d-array should be in the form array[counter][0] and array[counter][1] respectively, something like:

```
public static int[][] readMap(String[][] map){
        int counter = 0;
        int[][] wallAt = new int[map.length*map[0].length][2];   
        for(int x = 0; x < map.length ; x++){                   
            for(int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++){    
                if(map[x][y].equals("#")){
                    wallAt[counter][0] = x;
                    wallAt[counter][1] = y; 
                }  
                else{              
                    wallAt[counter][0] = 999;
                    wallAt[counter][1] = 999;
                }

                counter++;           
            }
        }
        return wallAt;                                             
    }
```